# Dynamic type casting for JsValue field in Scala Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework, casting

Since I'm writing a function to request data from another API in my Scala code, the response Json has the format like this:

```
"data": {
      "attributeName": "some String",
      "attributeValue": false,
      "attributeSource": "Manual",
      "attributeValueLabel": null
  },
 "data": {
      "attributeName": "some String",
      "attributeValue": "daily",
      "attributeSource": "Manual",
      "attributeValueLabel": "Almost Daily"
  }
```

Note that sometimes the type of `attributeValue` is `String` value, some other time it's a `Boolean` value.

So I'm trying to write my own Reads and Writes to read the type dynamically.

```
case class Data(attributeName: Option[String], attributeValue: Option[String], attributeSource: Option[String], attributeValueLabel: Option[String])

object Data{

  implicit val readsData: Reads[Data] = {
    new Reads[Data] {
      def reads(json: JsValue) = {
        val attrValue = (json \ "attributeValue").as[] // How to cast to Boolean some time, but some other time is a String here
        ......
      }
    }
  }
```

So as you can see in my comment, I'm stuck at the part to cast the `(json \ "attributeValue")`  to `String/Boolean`, base on the return type of the API. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to parse it as `String` first and then as `Boolean`:

```
val strO = (json \ "attributeValue").asOpt[String]
val value: Option[String] = strO match {
  case str@Some(_) => str
  case None        => (json \ "attributeValue").asOpt[Boolean].map(_.toString)
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer but this way does not work, it fails in the step to Parse to String because the actual type is Boolean

Comment: fixed. you need to check one or the other first

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.orElse` function when you are trying to read an attribute in different ways:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, Json, Reads}
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._


val json1 =
 """
   |{
   |  "attributeName": "some String",
   |  "attributeValue": false
   |}
 """.stripMargin

val json2 =
  """
    |{
    |  "attributeName": "some String",
    |  "attributeValue": "daily"
    |}
  """.stripMargin

// I modified you case class to make the example short
case class Data(attributeName: String, attributeValue: String)
object Data {

  // No need to define a reads function, just assign the value
  implicit val readsData: Reads[Data] = (
    (JsPath \ "attributeName").read[String] and

    // Try to read String, then fallback to Boolean (which maps into String)
    (JsPath \ "attributeValue").read[String].orElse((JsPath \ "attributeValue").read[Boolean].map(_.toString))
  )(Data.apply _)
}

println(Json.parse(json1).as[Data])
println(Json.parse(json2).as[Data])
```

Output:

```
Data(some String,false)
Data(some String,daily)
```